# How to determine if file has been modified in the last x seconds

Tags: bash, shell, date, time

I want to determine if a file has been modified in the last x seconds on MacOS or Debian etc.

```
is_file_older_than() {

  seconds="$1"
  file="$2"

  echo "The file $file"

  modified_secs="$(date -r "$file" +%s)"
  current_secs="$(date +%s)"

  diff="$(expr "$current_secs" - "$modified_secs")"

  if [[ "$diff" -gt "$seconds" ]]; then
    return 0
  fi

  return 1    
}

if is_file_older_than 3 "$BASH_SOURCE"; then
  echo 'old'
else
  echo 'young'
fi
```

but I am trouble verifying if it's working 100% and if there's anything unreliable - it looks like it's working

Comment: Does `date -r` on OS X work the same as GNU date?

Comment: I am not sure if it works the same, but it seems to

Comment: it says: `$ date -r
date: option requires an argument -- r
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: that means that it doesn't work the same. `touch foo; date -r foo` on MacOS will either print an error or tell you that `foo` is 49 years old.

Comment: I get this: `$ touch foo; date -r foo;
Wed Aug 28 17:16:27 PDT 2019`

Comment: that contradicts the usage above, which says `[-r seconds]`.

Comment: yeah that's weird

Comment: Yes, that should work, they just forgot to update the usage. `-r` will interpret its argument as a file if it's not a valid number (which means that a file named `33` will have to be given as `./33`). Source [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-203/date/date.c.auto.html) -- at `case 'r':`.

Comment: Looks like it's been updated in newer versions of *bsd `date`.  On my freebsd 12.0 VM it says `usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds|file] ...`.   that will probably eventually make its way into MacOS in future.

Comment: you could install GNU `coreutils` on MacOS with [brew](https://brew.sh/). then either run gdate on mac and date on linux, or `ln -s /path/to/date /path/to/gdate` on linux and run gdate on both.